# Populate data from another panda df conditionally?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I have a df1 with string objects in its 'Name' column.

Then there is a df2 with 'Categories' and 'Regex'.
df2.Regex holds regular expressions.

What I need to do is to:

- add a 'Category' column to df1;
- populate it with df2.Categories strings when their regex returns a match.

I'm new to Pandas and I suppose I might be taking this matter from a completely wrong angle. Feel free to throw my approach in the bin and send me on a better course ;-)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

flowers = {'Name':['Blue rose', 'Red rose', 'White rose', 'Green tulip', 'Rosy tulip', 'Yellow tulip']}
types = {'Categories':['Rose', 'Tulip'], 'Regex':[r'rose', r'tulip']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(flowers)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(types)

df1['Category'] = ???
```

I tried random things but none that produced any good results...

For example:

```
for x in df2.values:
    df['Portfolio'] = np.where(df.INSTRUMENT_NAME.str.contains(x[1]), x[0], 0)
```

Does not work because the for loop rewrites all the data added by previous iterations. Also np.where does not allow to simply pass when its condition is not met (or at least I don't know how to get it to work like that)

So to be clear, the expected result is:

```
df1
i    Name           Category
0    Blue rose      Rose
1    Red rose       Rose
2    White rose     Rose
3    Green tulip    Tulip
4    Rosy tulip     Tulip
5    Yellow tulip   Tulip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution is possible use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set values only for matched rows by condition:

```
for cat, reg in df2.values:
    mask = df1['Name'].str.contains(reg)
    df1.loc[mask, 'Category'] = cat

print (df1)
           Name Category
0     Blue rose     Rose
1      Red rose     Rose
2    White rose     Rose
3   Green tulip    Tulip
4    Rosy tulip    Tulip
5  Yellow tulip    Tulip
```

Or is possible use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with all values of `Regex` and then using [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df2.set_index('Regex')['Categories']
df1['Category'] = df1['Name'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(s.index)})', expand=False).map(s)

print (df1)
           Name Category
0     Blue rose     Rose
1      Red rose     Rose
2    White rose     Rose
3   Green tulip    Tulip
4    Rosy tulip    Tulip
5  Yellow tulip    Tulip
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. That's exactly what I was looking for.